# Passing params WebView in Flutter with FutureBuilder

Tags: html, flutter, plugins, webview

I'm trying to make an application with flutter and webview_flutter: 4.2.2, I'd like to have a dynamic URL in the webviewer but I can't get it.

I use a FutureBuilder to retrieve the IDs

Thank you very much for your help.

```
 Future<List> readData() async {
    [...]
    return [id, password];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: readData(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (globals.isLogged) {
              if (snapshot.data![0] != "" && snapshot.data![1] != "") {
                return Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, h * 0.06),
                        child: WebViewWidget(
                          controller: webViewController,
                        )),
                    isLoading
                        ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                        : Stack(),
                  ],
                );
              }
            }

           [...]
           );
  }
```

and the WebViewController :

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startLaunching();
  }

  late WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(urlfull));


  startLaunching() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final id = prefs.getString("id")!;
    String password = prefs.getString("password")!;
    urlfull =
    'https://www.my-test.com/application/smartphone_v3/process_login.asp?id=%27${id!}%27&pw=%27${password!}%27';
  }
```